# Through maven gettting error byte array is not a recognized imageformat

Tags: java, maven, pdf, itext

I'm trying to read an image present in one of the package and place it in my pdf (Using iText). When I deploy the application in my RAD-WAS it is successfully creating the PDF with the image. But when I generate the EAR through maven and deploy in WAS it shows error.

Piece of code is

```
InputStream inStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/myComp/pdf/logo/image.tif");
LOGGER.error("inStream = " +inStream);
Image img = null;
        try{

            img = Image.getInstance(IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream));
            LOGGER.error("img =" + img);

        }catch(IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Caught   IOException ="+ex);
        }
```

Output :

1) When Deployed locally

```
inStream = java.io.BufferedInputStream@10f910f9
```

and it runs successfully

2) When EAR generated through maven

```
inStream = com.ibm.ws.classloader.Handler$ZipEntryInputStream@489e489e 
Caught   IOException =java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
```

In my POM I have kept

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
       <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
       <version>7.0.0.19</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.jaxb.tools</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.19</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
....
<dependencies>
```

In my POM I have kept filter properties as below

```
<resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/${rad.sourcedir}
            </directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>*.classpath</exclude>
                <exclude>*.project</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

And also kept properties like

```
<properties>
    <application.systemletters>IRI</application.systemletters>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
.....
</properties>
```

I treid to remove the "this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream" by reading it as new File("..") but still isn't successful.

```
File file1 = new File("com/myComp/pdf/logo/image.tif"); 
          InputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file1); 
           LOGGER.error("fIn="+fIn);
          BufferedInputStream bIn = new BufferedInputStream(fIn);  
           LOGGER.error("bIn="+bIn);
Image img = null;
        try{

            img = Image.getInstance(IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream));
            LOGGER.error("img =" + img);

        }catch(IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Caught   IOException ="+ex);
        }
```

OutPut :

```
fIn=java.io.FileInputStream@3dac3dac
bIn=java.io.BufferedInputStream@c420c42
Caught   IOException =java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
```

Now, how do I get my image to come in PDF via maven also.

Comment: Have you configured your maven project to filter resources?

Comment: @mkl  Yes... I have edited my question to include the filter properties ... as I was not able to folrmat here in comments section....

Comment: Filtering usually breaks binary formats like images. Exclude those formats from filtering. Cf. [This page.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html)

Comment: @mkl you are right . Although when I tried to filter it by including the line <exclude>**/*.tif</exclude> it didn't work... However another approach i.e. changing from <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding> .... to <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> worked for the jpg images but failing for bmp files. I'm not exactly sure why this encoding parameter is at all required. This changing of encoding format resolves one issue but creates another issue.

Comment: *<exclude>**/*.tif</exclude>* - have you looked at the page i linked to? Have you tried `nonFilteredFileExtensions`? Playing around with file encoding changes the symptoms but does not resolve anything.

Comment: @mkl  It worked.. thanks a lot....It resolved all my issues... I excluded all kinds of binaries from my code and it worked.......